# javascript, получить значение поля

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как получить значение поля описанного следующим образом:

```
<input class="xxx" data-bem="b-input" type="text" name="firstname" required="true" pattern="^([^<>&amp;:&quot;]*[^<>&amp;:&quot;\s][^<>&amp;:&quot;]*|.{0})$" tabindex="1" maxlength="40">
```

Через document.getElementById('ххх').value - не получается так как нет ID
Через document.getElementsByClassName('ххх').value - тоже не получается

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('ххх')[0].value` ... но будет лучше `document.querySelector('.xxx').value`. — https://www.google.com/search?q=getelementsbyclassname+vs+queryselectorall&rlz=1C1CHBF_enAM856AM856&oq=getElementsByClassName+vs+&aqs=chrome.0.35i39j69i57j0l3j69i65.9096j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score -2):

мне помогло:

```
chrome.GetBrowser().GetFrame("").ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("(function(){ document.getElementsByName('firstname')[0].value = '" + tUsername.Text + "';})();");
```

Всем спасибо.

Comment: теперь я точно видел всё

Comment: да, мне тоже помогло, спасибо